# ServiceStack: How to transfer the original HttpRequest (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, request, servicestack

I am using a third-party [handset detection library](http://www.handsetdetection.com/) which receives the HttpRequest object as a parameter. My problem is that I need to have the code for using this library in a web-service.
I wanted to use [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) since it's supposed to be much faster than other technologies.

But by using ServiceStack I haven't found any way of sending the HttpRequest from my website to the service. I have found a way to set the UserAgent like this:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl);
client.LocalHttpWebRequestFilter = request => request.UserAgent = Request.UserAgent;
```

but nothing more than that.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What components of the HTTP request do you need to copy into the request sent to ServiceStack? (e.g. body? which headers? query string? cookies? etc.)

Comment: Actually I found that in the end I only needed the UserAgent, so it's all good now.

Comment: @SsjCosty I am cleaning up the ServiceStack open questions. Please can you add your `UserAgent` solution as an answer and accept it so this question can be closed. Thanks.